# What is the proper method of detecting the network inside of a Truffle test file?

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

Ropsten, Mainnet, or Ganache for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to know which truffle network key from the `truffle.js` was selected you can use the truffle object `deployer` which is passed as the first argument on the migration files (`$ROOT/migrations/*.js`), then add the value to the process.env, as in the following example:

**/migration/1_initial_migration.js**

```js
const Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = (deployer) => {
  process.env.NETWORK = deployer.network; // Network Id, for instance "ganache"

  deployer.deploy(Migrations).then(() => {
    console.log("Deployment of `Migrations.sol` completed");
  });
};
```

**/test/01_test.js**

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  let NETWORK = process.env.NETWORK;

  ...
  it("should ...", async () => {
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSON-RPC method `net_version`

See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version

> Returns string of the current network id.

```
"1": Ethereum Mainnet
"2": Morden Testnet (deprecated)
"3": Ropsten Testnet
"4": Rinkeby Testnet
"42": Kovan Testnet
```

Web3 exposes these methods: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3versionnetwork

---

Or to invoke the request manually:

```
    // The ganache GUI I have running returns "5777".
    // My embedded testRPC version returns whatever network ID is 
    // specified in truffle.js config, such as "*"
    let networkID = (await this.promisify(web3.currentProvider.sendAsync, {
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "net_version",
        params: [],
        id: 0
    })).result;

    // Both ganache and my embedded testRPC version return "63"
    let protocolVersion = (await this.promisify(web3.currentProvider.sendAsync, {
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "eth_protocolVersion",
        params: [],
        id: 0
    })).result;
```